# How Do I Compile Samba for Windows - Mainly SMBClient.exe?

Tags: windows-server-2012, samba, cygwin

I am using Pydio on a Windows Server 2012 R2 server for "cloud" file sharing. A situation has come up where we would like to connect to a existing share on another 2012 R2 server.  Pydio has a SMB wrapper that relies on SMBClient.exe being on the server.  If we were using *nix that would be easy but since it's hosted on a windows server we need a windows port of the client.  After a lot of searching I found someone that did just that (https://www.leepa.io/lpackham/smbclient/) and another person that did all of Samba (https://smithii.com/samba).  Unfortunately both are older version of the client and the do not work on the new Windows server.

Let me rephrase....you can read from a Windows server but you cannot put files...it creates 0 byte files and from research that happens with older versions of the Samba client (version 3's) on newer Windows servers (2012's).

Can anyone guide me on how to recompile the newest version of Samba for Windows?  I have attempted it myself using Cygwin but I cannot get it to make successfully and attempting to just compile the client part likewise hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of trial and error I was able to compile enough of Samba using Cygwin to get the smbclient.exe file compiled.  The steps needed:

Installed Windows XP SP3 32-bit on a virtual machine (I used VirtualBox)
Installed CygWin 32-bit with the Devel files
Extracted Samba 3.6.25
Navigated to the Source3 sub directory
Executed:

./configure --prefix=/usr/local/samba
make pch
make

The make failed on compiling net.exe but did so AFTER it successfully compiled smbclient.exe so I now have the client at version 3.6.25 and it does work on a 2012 R2 server.

-Allan